# Adicionando datasets do tipo object para o Reportviewer

Tags: reportviewer, configuração

Existe outra forma de adicionar o dataset do tipo objeto para criar os relatórios no reportviewer?

Nos exemplos que eu vejo é possível selecionar entre as opções: Database, Service, Object e SharePoint na tela de seleção do datasource. Porém, no meu projeto, ja passa direto para a janela de configuração do tipo Database.